# A clearer explanation for recursion and flow of execution in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I was reading Eloquent JavaScript and I came across this example for the puzzle:

> Consider this puzzle: By starting from
>   the number 1 and repeatedly either
>   adding 5 or multiplying by 3, an
>   infinite amount of new numbers can be
>   produced. How would you write a
>   function that, given a number, tries
>   to find a sequence of additions and
>   multiplications that produce that
>   number?

Here's the code for the solution:

```
function findSequence(goal) {
  function find(start, history) {
    if (start == goal)
      return history;
    else if (start > goal)
      return null;
    else
      return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
             find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
  }
  return find(1, "1");
}

print(findSequence(24));
```

Could someone clear up how dod find get executed if it didn't have a value for the arguments start and goal? Also how did the recursion happen?

Comment: See also [How does this recursion work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15712230/1048572) and [Javascript recursion from Eloquent Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26205376/1048572)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

But `find` *didn't* get executed without a value for `start` and `goal`. It was first executed with the value `1` for `start`, and the only value for `goal` was `24`.

Perhaps you're confused about the order of operations. There we see the *declaration* of a function, `findSequence`. During the declaration, no code is executed. The `findSequence` function only gets executed later, on the last line, where the result of executing the function gets printed out.

Within the declaration of `findSequence`, there's a declaration of another function, `find`. Once again, it doesn't get executed until later. The `findSequence` function has just *one* executable line of code, the one that calls `find(1, "1")`. Execution of that one line triggers the execution of `find` some number of times, recursively. The `find` function makes reference to `goal`; when the Javascript interpreter executes the code, `goal` always refers to the parameter of `findSequence`, and since in this example `findSequence` is only called once, `goal` always has the same value, `24`.

You should be able to see where the recursion happened. If `start` was equal to `goal`, then the function stops; it returns the history of how it arrived at that number. If `start` is greater than `goal`, then it returns `null`, indicating that that path was not a path to the target number. If `start` is still less than `goal`, then the function tries *calling itself* with its start value plus 5. If that returns a non-null value, then that's what gets returned. Otherwise, it tries multiplying by 3 and returning that history value instead.

Note that although this code can return many numbers, it cannot return *all* numbers. If the goal is `2`, for example, `findSequence` will return `null` because there is no way to start at `1` and get to `2` by adding `5` or multiplying by `3`.

Comment: `return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") || find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)")` , how this line work?

Answer (score 1):

When find is called inside of findSequence, it has access to the goal variable that is set in findSequence's definition.  A simple example of this is:

```
function outerFunction() {
  var a = 2;
  function innerFunction() {
    alert(a);
  }
  innerFunction();
}
outerFunction();
```

The start variable is defined when it does:

```
return find(1, "1");
```

Effectively having an initial start variable of 1, goal variable of 24, and a history of "1" on the first pass.

EDIT: Per Rob's comment, closures aren't actually what's causing this here, as find() is not being executed outside of findSequence(), scoping is causing goal to be found.

Comment: Does that really have anything to do with closures? I think it's just ordinary scope resolution: "find" has no "goal" identifier of its own, so it resolves to the one in the enclosing scope. Closures would only apply if "find" were called indirectly after "findSequence" had already returned.

Comment: yes actually, that's true, it's not a closures issue, just a scoping issue

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly: The final line of code is calling findSequence(), with a goal of 24.  In findSequence() there's a function called find(), which is defined and then called in the return statement for findSequence, with start equaling 1, and history equaling 1.