# How Is This Recursive Function Changing The 'history' Variable?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I feel so close to figuring this out, but I can't quite understand this function..

I get how the function keeps checking for the target number and if it gets too high, it returns null and the second '||' operator is applied.

What I do not understand is, once the current variable is higher than the target variable, it will start returning the history variable but without an additional (+5). How is this being taken out of the string?????

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated. Hopefully this makes sense. I am taking this from the book, Eloquent Javascript by Marijn Haverbeke

---

```js
function findSolution(target) {
  function find(current, history) {
    if (current == target) {
      return history;
    } else if (current > target) {
      //console.log(`CURRENT AT NULL: ` + current);
      console.log(`HISTORY AT NULL:  ${history}`);
      return null;

    } else {
      console.log(`${history}`);
      return find(current + 5, `(${history} + 5)`) ||
        find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`);
    }
  }
  return find(1, "1");
}
console.log(findSolution(24));
```

```
// → (((1 * 3) + 5) * 3)
```

Comment: Did you have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15712230/1048572)?

Comment: "*once the current variable is higher than the target variable, it will start returning the history variable*" - no. It does `return history` when the current is *equal* to the target variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing what's called a **depth-first search** via **recursion**.  Everyone groks recursion a little differently.  Something will eventually make it click for you.

I'd like to make a couple of annotations in your code that help it print out a more natural transcript of what transpires.  Hopefully that will help some.

But I think the most important thing is to visualize how many levels deep in the recursion you are with some indenting.  When you log during a recursive depth-first search, you are basically making a binary tree where the output is like:

```
Root
   Root > Left
   Root > Right
```

And it starts to nest with recursion like this:

```
Root
   Root > Left
      Root > Left > Left
      Root > Left > Right
   Root > Right
      Root > Right > Left
      Root > Right > Right
```

And instead of "Left" and "Right" paths, you are creating "+5" and "*3" branches of exploration.  In your recursion you explore the +5 branch of the tree first looking for a solution.  If you don't find it, then you explore the *3 branch of the tree.  When nothing is found, it just means that the answer does not lie on the branch you are considering and a different choice earlier in the tree must be made.

Some back-tracking appears to occur when both avenues are tried and neither succeeds.  But really it's just a conclusion of a hypothesis made where we say "can we get there if we +5?"  or "can we get there if we *3?"  If the answer is no to both, then you just can't get there from where you are.  You don't have to actually back-track, the beauty of recursion is that you got where you are in the search because someone invoked you as part of a "what if...".  If your entire search comes up empty, no problem. You just abandon your current branch of the search and the "someone" that invoked you will try something else on a different branch.

The state of your recursion (which branch you are exploring) is kept on your **call stack**.  That's where we actually "back up".

`history` is never modified.  We just explore different versions of `history` that are constructed via recursion.  Each `history` is its own copy and it only ever gets longer (a left or right branch in the search tree) or gets abandoned and the search continues from some other `history` elsewhere in the recursion.

So here's your code with some indenting and some wordy descriptions of what's going on at each step that hopefully ties back to the recursion a little more closely.

```js
function spaces(indent) {
  return '    '.repeat(indent);
}

function findSolution(target) {
  function nope(indent, history) {
    console.log(spaces(indent) + `Sadly we've exhausted all possible ways of getting there from this starting point.  We may still be able to get to ${target}, but not by starting from ${history}.`);
    return false;
  }
  function badnews(history) {
    console.log(`I've tried everything and there's just no way of getting to ${target}.  :(`);
    return false;
  }
  function find(current, which, history, indent) {
    if (current == target) {
      console.log(spaces(indent) + `${which}, and guess what...we finally found a solution! Because ${history} = ${current}.  So we can stop now. :)`);
      return history;
    } else if (current > target) {
      //console.log(`CURRENT AT NULL: ` + current);
      console.log(spaces(indent) + `${which}, we reached a dead end because ${history} = ${current} which is unfortunately already bigger than ${target}.`);
      return null;

    } else {
      console.log(spaces(indent) + `${which}, ${history} looks promising because it equals ${current}, which is still less than ${target}.  We'll try two ways of getting to ${target} from here.`);
      return find(current + 5, 'First, by adding 5', `(${history} + 5)`, indent+1) ||
        find(current * 3, 'Second, by multiplying by 3', `(${history} * 3)`, indent+1) ||
        nope(indent+1, history);
    }
  }
  return find(1, 'Initially', "1", 0) || badnews();
}
console.log(`${findSolution(24)}`);
```

Output is copied below, just in case.  Sorry, there's no wrapping of the output because indenting is more important so you can see how many levels deep in the recursion you are, and what causes a back-track.  You can run the snippet if you find the snippet console output more readable.

```
Initially, 1 looks promising because it equals 1, which is still less than 24.  We'll try two ways of getting to 24 from here.
    First, by adding 5, (1 + 5) looks promising because it equals 6, which is still less than 24.  We'll try two ways of getting to 24 from here.
        First, by adding 5, ((1 + 5) + 5) looks promising because it equals 11, which is still less than 24.  We'll try two ways of getting to 24 from here.
            First, by adding 5, (((1 + 5) + 5) + 5) looks promising because it equals 16, which is still less than 24.  We'll try two ways of getting to 24 from here.
                First, by adding 5, ((((1 + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) looks promising because it equals 21, which is still less than 24.  We'll try two ways of getting to 24 from here.
                    First, by adding 5, we reached a dead end because (((((1 + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) = 26 which is unfortunately already bigger than 24.
                    Second, by multiplying by 3, we reached a dead end because (((((1 + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) * 3) = 63 which is unfortunately already bigger than 24.
                    Sadly we've exhausted all possible ways of getting there from this starting point.  We may still be able to get to 24, but not by starting from ((((1 + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5).
                Second, by multiplying by 3, we reached a dead end because ((((1 + 5) + 5) + 5) * 3) = 48 which is unfortunately already bigger than 24.
                Sadly we've exhausted all possible ways of getting there from this starting point.  We may still be able to get to 24, but not by starting from (((1 + 5) + 5) + 5).
            Second, by multiplying by 3, we reached a dead end because (((1 + 5) + 5) * 3) = 33 which is unfortunately already bigger than 24.
            Sadly we've exhausted all possible ways of getting there from this starting point.  We may still be able to get to 24, but not by starting from ((1 + 5) + 5).
        Second, by multiplying by 3, ((1 + 5) * 3) looks promising because it equals 18, which is still less than 24.  We'll try two ways of getting to 24 from here.
            First, by adding 5, (((1 + 5) * 3) + 5) looks promising because it equals 23, which is still less than 24.  We'll try two ways of getting to 24 from here.
                First, by adding 5, we reached a dead end because ((((1 + 5) * 3) + 5) + 5) = 28 which is unfortunately already bigger than 24.
                Second, by multiplying by 3, we reached a dead end because ((((1 + 5) * 3) + 5) * 3) = 69 which is unfortunately already bigger than 24.
                Sadly we've exhausted all possible ways of getting there from this starting point.  We may still be able to get to 24, but not by starting from (((1 + 5) * 3) + 5).
            Second, by multiplying by 3, we reached a dead end because (((1 + 5) * 3) * 3) = 54 which is unfortunately already bigger than 24.
            Sadly we've exhausted all possible ways of getting there from this starting point.  We may still be able to get to 24, but not by starting from ((1 + 5) * 3).
        Sadly we've exhausted all possible ways of getting there from this starting point.  We may still be able to get to 24, but not by starting from (1 + 5).
    Second, by multiplying by 3, (1 * 3) looks promising because it equals 3, which is still less than 24.  We'll try two ways of getting to 24 from here.
        First, by adding 5, ((1 * 3) + 5) looks promising because it equals 8, which is still less than 24.  We'll try two ways of getting to 24 from here.
            First, by adding 5, (((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) looks promising because it equals 13, which is still less than 24.  We'll try two ways of getting to 24 from here.
                First, by adding 5, ((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) + 5) looks promising because it equals 18, which is still less than 24.  We'll try two ways of getting to 24 from here.
                    First, by adding 5, (((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) looks promising because it equals 23, which is still less than 24.  We'll try two ways of getting to 24 from here.
                        First, by adding 5, we reached a dead end because ((((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) = 28 which is unfortunately already bigger than 24.
                        Second, by multiplying by 3, we reached a dead end because ((((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) * 3) = 69 which is unfortunately already bigger than 24.
                        Sadly we've exhausted all possible ways of getting there from this starting point.  We may still be able to get to 24, but not by starting from (((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5).
                    Second, by multiplying by 3, we reached a dead end because (((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) + 5) * 3) = 54 which is unfortunately already bigger than 24.
                    Sadly we've exhausted all possible ways of getting there from this starting point.  We may still be able to get to 24, but not by starting from ((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) + 5).
                Second, by multiplying by 3, we reached a dead end because ((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) * 3) = 39 which is unfortunately already bigger than 24.
                Sadly we've exhausted all possible ways of getting there from this starting point.  We may still be able to get to 24, but not by starting from (((1 * 3) + 5) + 5).
            Second, by multiplying by 3, and guess what...we finally found a solution! Because (((1 * 3) + 5) * 3) = 24.  So we can stop now. :)
(((1 * 3) + 5) * 3)
```

Comment: This is above and beyond anything I could have asked for! I think it is starting to come together a little better for me now. Especially the info about depth-first search & indenting the console.log output. I am still not 100% clear on why the program runs this way to go forward and backwards as so, but I think I will watch a couple videos/read up until it is ingrained in my head haha. I have a much better understanding now, thanks to everyones help! This community is amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your `current > target` so it returns `null` and you're `find(current * 3,`(${history} * 3)`)` will be evaluated

suppose

```
((((1 + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5)   ---> This is the current value of history
```

So the current value at present is `21`

Now when you reach

```
   find(current + 5, `(${history} + 5)`) ||
        find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`);
```

It calls the **find(21 + 5, `(${history} + 5)`))** since the value of `current > target` so the value returned from this call will be null, since null is falsy value so the second operand will be call,

```
  find(21 * 3, `(${history} * 3)`);   <--- so this is the final value returned form this invocation
```

So the value of history here will

```
(((((1 + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) * 3)
```

---

```js
function findSolution(target) {
  function find(current, history) {
    if (current == target) {
      return history;
    } else if (current > target) {
      console.log(current, ' ---> ', `HISTORY AT NULL:  ${history}`);
      return null;

    } else {
      console.log(current,' ---> ', `${history}`);
      return find(current + 5, `(${history} + 5)`) ||
        find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`);
    }
  }
  return find(1, "1");
}
console.log(findSolution(8));
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for your input! I understood up to this point.. However, I get lost when I see this.. 'HISTORY AT NULL:  ((((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5)'
'HISTORY AT NULL:  ((((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) * 3)'
'HISTORY AT NULL:  (((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) + 5) * 3)'
'HISTORY AT NULL:  ((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) * 3)' .   Why is the "+5"  being taken away while current > target?

Comment: @Grant try to understand it with a small value, see the snippet, here target is `8`, so first iteration it will be `(1+5)` which is less than `8`, next value will be `( 1 + 5 ) + 5)` this value is higher than `8` so, the function after `||` will be called so the value will be `(1 + 5) * 3`, so it returns null so it goes back to part where we passed `( 1 + 5 )` and try to pass `( 1 * 3 )` and then in next iteration it passes `( 1 * 3) + 5` which is equal to target so it return from there

Comment: I think my main issue is where you say "so it goes back to part where we passed ( 1 + 5 ) and try to pass ( 1 * 3 )". I understand that this is what it is doing. My issue is that I am trying to run the iteration of how this works logically in my head and I cannot wrap my head around HOW the the program is actually doing this. Regardless, I really appreciate that you have taken the time to help me understand! Maybe I need to take a fresh look at it tomorrow when my mind is clearer.

Comment: I guess my main confusion is: if current is greater than target. Then shouldn't this program just be stuck in an infinite loop of returning Null and continuously restarting the program since Current wouldn't be changing? Maybe if I understand why this is not the case, I will have a much better understanding. Again, thank you so much!