# Could someone please illustrate this recursive function?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I've read all the documentation on recursive functions and Math.max but I still don't quite understand how this function works. Can someone explain what's happening here step by step? In particular, the second return statement involving Math.max().

```js
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  // split the string into individual words
  const words = str.split(" ");

  // words only has 1 element left that is the longest element
  if (words.length == 1) {
    return words[0].length;
  }

  // if words has multiple elements, remove the first element
  // and recursively call the function
  return Math.max(
    words[0].length,
    findLongestWordLength(words.slice(1).join(' '))
  );
}

console.log(findLongestWordLength("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

Comment: This is a typical recursive function. There is the base case and recursive case. If you know what `Math.max` does, then what exactly do you not understand? The recursive call? What is passed as argument to the recursive call? What it returns? How that is compared with the first word's length? I'd suggest stepping through the code with a debugger while you inspect the involved expressions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does this recursion work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712230/how-does-this-recursion-work)

Comment: @Heretic Monkey that confused me even more tbh, I don't even know how to begin understanding that

Answer (score 1):

Why would someone write something so terrible!

Let's look at "hello goodbye all"

This code is saying:

1. Break it up into words ['hello', 'goodbye', all']
2. If there is only one word, it's length is the answer
3. If there is more than one word, find the length of the first word.
4. Put everything except the first word back into a string (WTF!?!) and recursively find the longest word in that.
5. Take the maximum of those two values calculated in steps 3 and 4.

The idea of breaking the string into words, and then putting all the words except the first back into a string just so you can call yourself recursively is pretty bizarre.

So a typical run looks like:

```
findLongestWordLength('hello goodbye all')
    = max(5, findLongestWordLength('goodbye all'))
    = max(5, max(7, findLongestWordLength('all')))
    = max(5, max(7, 3))
    = max(5, 7)
    = 7
```

Note that this is the standard trick of recursion.  You prove the code works by assuming that it works on everything that is shorter.

Obviously this code works on all strings with one word in it.  And given a string with `n > 1` words in it, you assume that you're going to get the right answer when you call it with a string with `n - 1` words in it, and then use that to get the right answer for your current string.

Comment: It's the 4th and 5th step that I don't get. On the first call, the function finds the length of [0], in your example 'hello', which is 5, and puts 'goodbye all' back into a string, and then what? At what point Math.max is applied? The second value of Math.max is always a string, so how is it comparing the first numerical value to it? Here's where I'm stuck.

Comment: It is indeed needlessly overcomplicated; a single line of code such as `return Math.max(...str.split(' ').map(word => word.length))` has the same effect.

Comment: @Lemondoge yes i know and that was my initial solution, but I'm just trying to understand this solution using recursion

Comment: Expanded my code to answer your question.

Comment: Please "approve" the answer if you're happy.