# Why does this program keep on running after null is returned?

Tags: javascript, recursion, null

I'm learning recursion and I understand how the program generally works, but I'm confused why the program continues to work after null is first returned when the value, at 16, is too big.

Basically the code below will run and add 5 to the argument for start each time from 1,6,11 to 16. Since 16 is > 13 it says to return null. How does JavaScript know to go back and try to calculate 13 when it just says return null on line 6?

I'd really appreciate any help. Here's the code from the book I'm looking at:

```
function findSolution(target) {
  function find(start, history) {
    if (start == target)
      return history;
    else if (start > target)
      return null;
    else
      return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
             find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
  }
  return find(1, "1");
}

console.log(findSolution(13));
```

Comment: To be clear, it works just fine, you're just asking how it works

Answer (score 2):

The main culprit is:

```
  return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
         find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
```

Lets assume `start` is equal to 1 and, like with your code, our target is 13.

1. `find()` is called with our 1 to begin with. Lets call this *Find A*.
2. `find()` gets to the snippet above and is triggered again with a new `start` value of `1 + 5` (6). Let's call this *Find B*.
3. *Find B* also gets to the snippet above and is triggered again with a new `start` value of `6 + 5` (11). Let's call this *Find C*.
4. *Find C* also gets to the snippet above and is triggered again with a new `start` value of `11 + 5` (16). Let's call this *Find D*.
5. *Find D* returns the value `null` to *Find C*.
6. *Find C* executes the OR parameter of the above snippet. `find()` is triggered again with a new `start` value of `6 * 3` (18). Let's call this *Find E*.

See what's happening?

7. *Find E*, like with our deceased friend *Find D* returns the value `null` to *Find C*.
8. *Find C* now returns the value `null` to *Find B*.
9. *Find B* executes the OR parameter of the above snippet.

Eventually your recursion will end when a value other than `null` is returned to your original *Find A* call, but it still has a way to go before it reaches the original *Find A* and finally returns a value to our `findSolution()` function.

For every `null` response, a new `find()` call is made. `null` is a falsey value. Until a truthy value is returned (your `history` variable in this case), new `find()` functions will be executed. When the `history` variable is returned, it gets passed back to the calling function, which passes it back to its calling function, until eventually it makes it back to our *Find A* function call which passes it back to the `findSolution()` function.

---

#### A working visualisation

You'll need to open your JavaScript console for this.

```js
var findIteration = 0;

function findSolution(target) {
  function find(start, history, caller) {
    var thisIteration = ++findIteration;
    console.log("Find Iteration " + thisIteration, "Start: " + start, "Called by: " + caller);
    if (start == target)
      return history;
    else if (start > target)
      return null;
    else
      return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)", thisIteration) ||
             find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)", thisIteration);
  }
  return find(1, "1", 0);
}

console.log(findSolution(13));
```

Here's what our console output looks like:

[image: Example]

The "Called By" here is the `find()` method that called it - just like how *Find C* (iteration 3) calls *Find E* (iteration 5) in the text example I was giving at the start.

All in all, our `find()` function was called 9 separate times before finally reaching the correct value.

Comment: @James_Donnelly Thanks for your help. There's just one thing I still don't get. How is caller modified in this code? I don't see where you say to change it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. There's just one thing I still don't get. How is caller modified in this code? I don't see where you say to change it

Comment: @Gwater17 what do you mean by "change it"? What are you trying to change?

Comment: I don't want to change anything.. I just don't understand how the value of caller is altered each time the function runs.              You never say to add 1 or subtract 1 from caller or whatever

Comment: @Gwater17 you don't need to. The function calls itself, meaning the function executes multiple times. If it's null, the function calls itself. If the function that it called is null, that also calls itself. Only when one of the functions isn't null will it bubble back to the original function and return a value.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the code - it works in [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6jc9s2be/1/):

```
return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
             find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
```

This is basically checking the first call against find() and a second call through the `||` or comparison. When the function `returns null`. Javascript `null` is considered `false` in a logical or operation. So when both find() calls return null, the recursion would stop.