# How does JavaScripts's Recursive OR work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

*Question: does any combination of numbers in the array sum to the array's largest number?*

There is a Coderbyte answer, [original source](https://coderbyte.com/question/array-addition-recursion), that I cannot get my head around. I am trying to visualize this function in action, but it just doesn't make sense to me. Here is is:

```
function ArrayAdditionI(arr) { 
  arr.sort(function(a,b){
    return a - b;
  });
  var largest = arr.pop();
  function recursion(target,array){
    if(array.length === 0){
      return target === 0; 
    }
    var n = array[0];
    array = array.slice(1);
    return recursion(target,array) || recursion(target - n, array);
  }
  return recursion(largest,arr);        
}
```

Therefore, given:

```
[3,5,-1,8,12]
```

It should output:

```
"true"
```

My interpretation is that the return statement will call each function around the `||`, and subsequently any produced from those, etc, until the array's length is `0`. But how is it checking for the proper addends for the largest number?

Comment: While not exactly the same, I encourage you to have a look at [Javascript recursion from Eloquent Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26205376/1048572) and the other questions linked from there

Comment: Note that the `||` operator doesn't have anything in particular to do with the notion of recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
  return recursion(target,array) || recursion(target - n, array);
```

calls `recursion()` first with the target sum and the array with the first element stripped off. If that returns `true` (because `target` is zero and the array is empty), then the right-hand side of the `||` will *not* be called. Only if that first call returns `undefined` or `false` will the right-hand side call be made.

So the overall process is to first find the largest value, and invoke the recursive process with that and the rest of the list. Repeatedly, the recursive routine pries off the first value and then checks to see if there's a sum equal to the target in the rest of the list, *or* if there's a sum equal to the target *minus* that pried-off first value in the rest of the list.

It helps to slightly rearrange the function so that the behavior can be traced:

```
function ArrayAdditionI(arr) { 
  arr.sort(function(a,b){
    return a - b;
  });
  var largest = arr.pop();
  function recursion(target,array){
    if(array.length === 0){
      return target === 0; 
    }
    var n = array[0];
    array = array.slice(1);
    console.log("target: " + target + " n: " + n);
    var r1 = recursion(target,array), r2 = recursion(target - n, array);
    console.log("(" + target + ", " + n + ") left: " + r1 + " right: " + r2);
    return r1 || r2;
  }
  return recursion(largest,arr);        
}
```

If you call that with the sample array:

```
ArrayAdditionI([3,5,-1,8,12]);
```

you get the following trace:

```
target: 12 n: -1
target: 12 n: 3
target: 12 n: 5
target: 12 n: 8
(12, 8) left: false right: false
target: 7 n: 8
(7, 8) left: false right: false
(12, 5) left: false right: false
target: 9 n: 5
target: 9 n: 8
(9, 8) left: false right: false
target: 4 n: 8
(4, 8) left: false right: false
(9, 5) left: false right: false
(12, 3) left: false right: false
target: 13 n: 3
target: 13 n: 5
target: 13 n: 8
(13, 8) left: false right: false
target: 8 n: 8
(8, 8) left: false right: true
(13, 5) left: false right: true
target: 10 n: 5
target: 10 n: 8
(10, 8) left: false right: false
target: 5 n: 8
(5, 8) left: false right: false
(10, 5) left: false right: false
(13, 3) left: true right: false
(12, -1) left: false right: true
```

So the left-hand side of the `||` represents the approach of seeing whether you can find the sum *without* considering one of the values, and the right-hand side considers whether you can find the sum assuming one of the values is one of the constituents. From the first few lines, you see the recursion skipping through the first four values, smallest to largest, until the array on the last call is empty. The target value is still `12`, so that didn't work.

Then there's the attempt to include the value `5` (when `target` is `12`), giving a target of `7` and a list with just `8` in it; that doesn't work either. Continuing, it's only when the process gets to the right-hand side in the original invocation, with `target` as `12` and `n` as `-1` that things start looking up. Because `12 - -1` is `13`, and `13 - 5` is `8`, and `8 - 8` is `0`, there is a group of values that sums up to the target.

Comment: Wait, I still don't get how any of the sums are being computed.

Comment: @pward the *sums* aren't being computed, at least not directly. The key is that `target - n` thing. That causes the process to try and find a possible group of values when `n` *does* participate; the left-hand side is to check for when `n` *doesn't* participate.

Comment: but if `n` is shaved off after the first go around, then how will the function be able to check all possible combinations of the array?

Comment: @pward in the first go-round, the only number that's either considered or not is the first (smallest) element. Clearly, if there is a "sum group", each element is either part of that or it isn't. Thus, that `||` manifests that fact: either a number in the array *is* part of a group that sums to the largest value, or it isn't.

Comment: it isn't clear how the function is checking if any combination adds to the largest variable if no summing is involved...whether a index participates or not isn't the question - the question is, given this state of *in* or *out*, in what will they be participating? The answer to that would be an additive equation, but since no adding or subtracting from a sum is involved, there is no way for the *in* or *out* state to be determined. Note that I am not arguing with you, only making more clear what is evident to me and what isn't in this function.

Comment: Subtraction is the opposite of summing. If some of the numbers can be subtracted from the target and end up with no more numbers and a target of `0`, then you've found a "summing group". There **is** a "subtraction from a sum" - that's what `target - n` does.

Comment: Think of that `||` expression as meaning, "maybe this number (n) *isn't* in the group, or maybe it *is*."

Comment: It might help if you would draw out a tree diagram with the both sides of the `||` step by step. Probably it'd be easier to start with a 3-element array :)

Comment: I'll have to do that it looks look. I'm feeling like that quote right now: "In order to understand recursion, you must first understand recursion." When I figure it out I'll make a blog post about it and post it here. Thanks for your patience : )

Comment: To be fair, this is sort-of a "tricky" way of solving the problem. It's not bad or wrong, but for instructional purposes one could probably think of something a little more straightforward.

Comment: I recently worked through the "Two-sum" problem using a straight-forward approach (nested for loops) and recursion, and the recursive approach was 75% faster.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116703/discussion-between-pward-and-pointy).

Comment: I believe I have resolved the mystery for myself on this! After some help thinking about it, it seems the crux of the mystery was the "solve for zero" approach to sum checking that I have not really used much since high school. Check out the reddit post here: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/4roxb0/javascript_how_does_this_this_recursive_function/

Answer (score 0):

May this helps to understand `||`:

```
true  || 1 // => true
false || 1 // => 1


function returnTrue() {
  return true;
}

function returnFalse() {
  return false
}

returnTrue()   || 1 // => true
returnFalse()  || 1 // => 1
```