# Can't get javascript recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

This example is from Eloquant javascript and I can't get how it works. I got how basically the recursion works though from other basic examples. Can anyone explain to me know how this works?

It is explained on the link below.
http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html

```
function findSolution(target){
    function find(start, history){
        if (start == target)
            return history;
        else if (start > target) {
            return null;
        }
        else
            return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
                    find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)")
    }
    return find(1, "1");
} 

findSolution(24));
//answer
//"(((1 * 3) + 5) * 3)"
```

Comment: duplicate of [See also A clearer explanation for recursion and flow of execution in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/720158/1048572), [How does this recursion work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15712230/1048572) and [Javascript recursion from Eloquent Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26205376/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to understand how the returns work for the inner function.

```
return func(A) || func(B)
```

If func(A) is not null it's returned, otherwise func(B)

Now our target is 24 and the starting point would be `find(1, 1)` (the return value of the outer function which triggers the recursive function)

find(1, 1) may have two possible outputs:

```
A: find(6, (1+5))
or
B find(3, (1*3))
```

B will be on hold unless we get a null return from A (or reach the target), so we continue with A, the return will be:

```
Aa: find(11, ((1+5)+5))
or
Ab: find(15, ((1+5)*3))
```

Again Ab on hold and we continue with Aa which will return:

```
Aa1: find(16, (((1+5)+5)+5))
Aa2: find(33, (((1+5)+5)*3))
```

Aa2 is bigger than target (24) so it will never continue. So we continue with Aa1 which will return 21 and then 25 which passes the target and so returns null. So we go back to Ab which returns 45 > target. So `A` returns null anyway and now we try B:

```
Ba: find(8, ((1*3)+5))
Bb: find(9, ((1*3)*3))
```

Continue with Ba which then returns:

```
Ba1: find(13, (((1*3)+5)+5))
Ba2: find(24, (((1*3)+5)*3))
```

We continue with Ba1 which will return 18 and then 23 and then 28 which is bigger than target and so null. So go back to `Ba2` which is `24 == target` and so finishes the calculation and returns its history which is:

```
(((1*3)+5)*3)
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/ztbxr7k8/1/)
You can see the log of all the end points (when null reached or finally when a match found).

**EDIT:**
This is how the function will execute:

```
//instead of find I use f
findSolution(24) >
f(1, 1) >
    f(6, (1+5)) >
        f(11, ((1+5)+5)) >
            f(16, (((1+5)+5)+5)) >
                f(21, ((((1+5)+5)+5)+5)) >
                    f(26, (((((1+5)+5)+5)+5)+5)) > NULL
                    f(63, (((((1+5)+5)+5)+5)*3)) > NULL
                f(48, ((((1+5)+5)+5)*3)) > NULL
            f(33, (((1+5)+5)*3)) > NULL
        f(18, ((1+5)*3)) >
            f(23, (((1+5)*3)+5)) >
                f(28, ((((1+5)*3)+5)+5)) > NULL
                f(69, ((((1+5)*3)+5)*3)) > NULL
            f(54, (((1+5)*3)+5)) > NULL
    f(3, (1*3)) >
        f(8, ((1*3)+5)) >
            f(13, (((1*3)+5)+5)) > 
                f(18, ((((1*3)+5)+5)+5)) >
                    f(23, (((((1*3)+5)+5)+5)+5)) >
                        f(28, ((((((1*3)+5)+5)+5)+5)+5)) > NULL
                        f(69, ((((((1*3)+5)+5)+5)+5)*3)) > NULL
                    f(54, (((((1*3)+5)+5)+5)*3)) > NULL
                f(39, ((((1*3)+5)+5)*3)) > NULL
            f(24, (((1*3)+5)*3)) > MATCH
```

Comment: I think this should be a great explanation but I just can't get it working on my brain.. I feel my stupid.. myself.. I will keep thinking until I understand.. Thank you all.

Comment: I think I got it.Thank you a lot Samurai. the jsdiffle demo helped a lot.

Comment: No worries, added the execution trees so it might be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. function findSolution(target){
 2.    function find(start, history){
 3.        if (start == target)
 4.            return history;
 5.        else if (start > target) {
 6.            return null;
 7.        }
 8.        else
 9.            return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
10.                    find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)")
11.    }
12.    return find(1, "1");
13. } 
14.
15. findSolution(24);
```

When line 15 calls the function `findSolution`, 24 is passed in for `target`. Inside the function `findSolution`, another function `find` is defined. This function is then called using `find(1, "1")` on line 12, which starts the recursion.  On the first pass of this recursion, a check is made to see if the recursion is completed.  This happens when `start` is equal to `target` (line 3), which is the value given previously for `findSolution` (on line 15).  In this case, it won't on the first pass, so it proceeds to the next part on line 5.  On this line it checks if the start value has gone beyond the target, and if so, returns null.  If NOT, then it proceeds to line 9, which recursively calls `find` with the current `start` value (1 on the first pass), plus 5 (so 6), and if fails (null is returned [see line 6]), the second call on line 10 occurs because of the `||` operator.  This tries `start*3`, and on the first pass, this is `1*3`, or 3.  This keeps going until it has gone as far as it can adding to or multiplying the `start` value.

In a nutshell, the recursion keeps going via `find` while start does not reach the target.  It ends when either the `start` value is an exact match to `target` (line 3), or if the target cannot be reached because of the test on line 5, which doesn't allow `start + 5` or `start * 3` to go beyond it.